# Referencing the ith element of each list in a 2d list

Tags: python, dictionary, subscript

Take a 2d list.
I want to make a new list with only the ith element from each list.
What is the best way to do this?

I have:

```
 map(lambda x: x[i], l)
```

Here is an example

```
 >>> i = 0
 >>> l = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]
 >>> map(lambda x: x[i], l)
 [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
i = 1
data = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]
result = [d[i] for d in data]  # [10, 20, 30]
```

Also see this question on [list comprehension vs. map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486).

Comment: or to fit into the original question `result = [x[i] for x in l]`

Comment: FYI A list comprehension is more highly optimized than map.